# How can i set the position of text?

Tags: android, textview

I have a problem that I want to set the position of text as to from particular location.

For example:I have this text in my textview: `abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrstu vwxyz`

Now, I want this text to show from location `efgh` rather than `abcd`
How can I perform this operation in textview? I want to change the position of text and not the position of textview.

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with position? Just remove the abcd from the string.

Comment: I have to do this thing in particular condition only not everywhere

Comment: @Falmarri: It's an example...

Comment: @kcoppock: An example of what exactly? What rule can you infer from this example that can possibly answer the question?

Comment: @falmarri: Positioning, not content.

Comment: Use margin_left attribute in your xml example : android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"

Comment: but i want it dynamically through programming

Comment: Nikki, I added a programmatic solution into my answer.

Comment: @kcoppock: How the hell do you get that he wants to change the margins from the question? How does `Now i want this text to show from location "efgh" rather than "abcd"` imply margins?

Comment: @Falmarri: Just making inferences from the question. The subject "position of text", the space breaks in the example text, "position of text and not the position of textview" tells me he wants to reposition the text. Not disagreeing that simply using the word "margin" would have been less vague, but I'm getting used to vague questions here on SO. @.@

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nikki, just add a marginLeft attribute to your TextView like so:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Testing"
    />
```

where you just substitute whatever value you want for the left margin.

EDIT: For code, you should be able to use the following:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom); //use ints here
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

And just for the hell of it, here's how to do it in one line :)

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).setMargins(left, top, right, bottom));
```

Comment: but this will set the textview position and i want to set text position and not textview position.

Comment: Then it is even simpler. Just use `tv.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom)` where "left" is the distance from the edge of the TextView.

Comment: although the question was very misleading, bravo for @kcoppock for understanding and answering it! :)